# Passing data from dialog to activity that is created

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to get one string, two integers and one timepicker result from a dialog to the activity where this dialog is created. How can I pass this information to this activity? 
Below there is my code.

```
package ilachatirlatici.pack.net;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

public class HapHatirlatici extends Activity{

Button ekleButton;
boolean eklendiMi;
EditText ilacAdi;
String ilacAdiString;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.haphatirlatici);

    // After creating the activity setting other things for running
    ekleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.EkleButton);
    eklendiMi = false;
    ilacAdiString = "";
    ekleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ilacAdi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KayitAdiEditText);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ekle_dialog, null);                               
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HapHatirlatici.this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ekle,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                eklendiMi = true;
                ilacAdiString =  ilacAdi.getText().toString();
                //ilacAdiString = ilacAdi.getEditableText().toString();
                databaseEkle(eklendiMi, ilacAdiString);
           }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.vazgec, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                eklendiMi = false;
                databaseEkle(eklendiMi, "");
           }
        });
        builder.setView(layout);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Ilac Ekleme");
        alertDialog.show();


        }
    });
}
public boolean databaseEkle(boolean eklemeVarMi, String ilacAdi)
{
    boolean sonuc = false;
    System.out.println(ilacAdi);
    return sonuc;
}

}
```

I am trying to get the result in positive button part. I only implemented the string part. Since the other parts will be same. How can I pass this string to the `databaseEkle()` function?

Comment: doesn't it seems like you are already passing the value ?

Comment: Yes it seems like that. But when it enters to the positive button part the application says force closing. that parts throws nullpointer exception.

Comment: can you also paste the exception stack trace.

Comment: with a try catch statement it is seen that it throws a nullpointerexception. because of a reason which is not known it cannot get the string from the dialog. has anyone idea about that?

Comment: can you put what the LogCat says? just by saying nullPointer, its hard to guess the problem

Comment: The exception stack trace is
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at ilachatirlatici.pack.net.HapHatirlatici$1$1.onClick(HapHatirlatici.java:35)
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-26 00:00:21.465: W/System.err(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 00:00:21.475: W/System.err(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-26 00:00:21.475: W/System.err(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-26 00:00:21.475: W/System.err(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-26 00:00:21.475: W/System.err(376):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Met

Comment: if you comment everything in your onClick of positive button, then does it still crash?

Comment: When I comment the line ilacAdiString =  ilacAdi.getText().toString(); everything is fine..

Comment: are you using EditText `ilacAdi` inside your alert dialog to input text?

Comment: bingo!  check my answer. hope it should fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to access EditText which is actually inside AlertDialog's layout **R.layout.ekle_dialog**. You need to refer to your inflated layout to reference to edittext.

set your button's onClick listener like this:

```
ekleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ekle_dialog, null);
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.KayitAdiEditText);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HapHatirlatici.this);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ekle,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            eklendiMi = true;
            ilacAdiString =  myEditText.getText().toString();
            //ilacAdiString = ilacAdi.getEditableText().toString();
            databaseEkle(eklendiMi, ilacAdiString);
       }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.vazgec, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            eklendiMi = false;
            databaseEkle(eklendiMi, "");
       }
    });
    builder.setView(layout);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Ilac Ekleme");
    alertDialog.show();


    }
});
```

in this example i'm using `myEditText` instead of `ilacAdi` because you have declared your editText global, which doesn't need to be in this case